# Knapsack with repetition - array solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am trying to understand a knapsack algorithm given to me in class, specifically the following pseudocode.

[image]

This was my attempt to code it:

```
//Init array
var solution = [];
var items = problem.items;
var sackSize = problem.knapsack;

solution[0] = 0;
for(var k = 1; k <= sackSize; k++)
{
    var loot = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= items.length; i++)
    {
        if(k >= items[i].weight)
        {
            loot = Math.max(loot, items[i].value)
        }
    }
    solution[k] = loot;
}
```

This doesn't make sense to me because `if(k >= items[i].weight)` always gives an "index out of bounds" error on the last iteration of the loop. The `items` array starts at index 0 but `i` starts at 1. Why are we starting at index 1? Am I misinterpreting the variables?

I am given:

> The object problem includes the maximum weight of the knapsack
>   (problem.knapsack) and an array of available items (problem.items).
>   Each item is an object with a weight and value attribute
>   (problem.items[i].weight and problem.items[i].value). Both of these
>   functions should return an array of selected items. The items in the
>   returned array should also have weight and value attributes.

Comment: It is common in pseudo codes to iterate from `1` to `n` rather than `0` to `n-1`. Just because the pseudo code iterates from `1` to `n` does not mean your code also has to iterate from `1` to `n` especially when you know that array index starts at `0`.

Comment: @wookie919 so do you think the solution is not dependent on it starting at 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at each element of the `items` array. The first element is `items[0]` and the last element is `items[items.length-1]`.

Therefore, you should change the line

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= items.length; i++)
```

to this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
```

Now `items[i].weight` will be valid on the last iteration.

So why does the pseudocode say the following?

```
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
```

Well, the pseudocode is using a mathematical convention in which items are numbered from 1 through `n`. Your code has a different convention in which items are numbered from `0` through `items.length-1`.

That's not the only difference between your code and the pseudocode. For example, you're writing `k >= items[i].weight` instead of `k ≥ W[i]`. Also, you're declaring local variables with the `var` notation. That's because your code is a practical implementation. The pseudocode is a mathematical abstraction.

The abstract idea in the pseudocode is to look at the items one by one, which is expressed mathematically as considering `W[1]` through `W[n]`. In your code, the first item is `items[0]` and the last one is `items[items.length-1]`. You must write the `for` statement accordingly.

Ah, but what about the knapsack capacity? Do we have to change that loop index as well? The answer is no. Here we're dealing with a different index that has a different meaning. Instead of looking up items in an array, we're making a new array that we want to index with values from 0 through `sackSize`. The value of `solution[k]` is an optimal packing for a knapsack of capacity `k`.

To make this clear, I suggest that you declare the `solution` array like this:

```
var solution = new Array(sackSize+1);
```

By the way, the assignment is asking you to do more than the pseudocode is doing. The pseudocode only computes the total value that you can achieve with an optimal packing. The assignment is asking you to return an array of items used in an optimal packing.

Comment: looking at my code i wrote `loot = Math.max(loot, items[i].value)` but the pseudocode for that line is a little more complicated. Not sure if i missed that or what, but should I being doing the more complicated one?

Comment: Yes, that's necessary to calculate the solution correctly. `loot = Math.max(loot, items[i].value + solution[k - items[i].weight]);`

Comment: what if there are infinite number of same object. how to work that out?

Comment: @Bear - You can replace the current `if` statement with a `for` loop that iterates over a variable, let's say `count`, representing the number of items of type `i`. Keep incrementing `count` as long as the items fit within `k`, the current knapsack limit. The whole loop would look something like this: `for (var count = 1; count * items[i].weight <= k; ++count) { loot = Math.max(loot, count * items[i].value + solution[k - count * items[i].weight]); }`